# power monitoring capabilities of ibm x3550 m4

Tags: monitoring, electrical-power, ibm-xseries

I don't understand how monitoring of power consumption of x series
servers is done with IBM AEM - I'm specifically interested in
x3550 m4. The documentation on the servers does not really 
highlight the power monitoring capabilities and the IMM2 does
not seem to give power consumption info.

Any pointers on where AEM gets this info? Also, is it possible
to access it without using IBM tools?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of digging, I found the answer to my q - there is an old library in the hwmon part of linux that can talk to the AEM functions on the BMC. So it's possible to directly query the machine for the realtime power consumption.

More info here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaai.energymgmt%2Fliaaienergyloadmod.htm